# inno setup icons filename in server

Tags: inno-setup

hi i am havinf trouble with icons,on the setup part i have got this:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon="X:\Design\IdOntime\icon_ontime.ico"
```

this icon is in a server, and i can reach the server folder in a mapped drive, in this case x:.
So this is saying where the uninstall icon is, and when i run setup the uninstall icon appear correclty.
Now moving to the icons on the desktop and the init menu..

```
  [Icons]
  Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}";  IconFilename: "X:\Design\IdOntime\icon_ontime.ico"
  Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon; IconFilename: "X:\Design\IdOntime\icon_ontime.ico"
```

i am using the same path, but this time instead of the icon , it appears a blank page. What i can understant is that the windows didnt find the icon so it is puting a default icon.

what is even more stange is that if i change the path of the icon to a local path, it works. 
so does inno setup icons section doenst like mapped path?

thanks in advance..

Comment: From the documentation: IconFilename
The filename of a custom icon (**located on the user's system**) to be displayed. This can be an executable image (.exe, .dll) containing icons or a .ico file. If this parameter is not specified or is blank, Windows will use the file's default icon. Does the app where the application is installed contain a drive mapped to `X:` containing the folders you've listed? The path is **on the users system** after the installation. Add the icon file to the `Files` section, have it installed to the `{app}` directory, and then set the `IconFilename` there.

Comment: yes, x is refering to a ServerDev\ProjectosSA, inside i have got the design folder with the icons.

Comment: so the problem is when it says that the icons should be in the user system (does this include mapped directories)?

Comment: i could work around and send the icon file within the files to a temp directory or tje app directory, then fecth the file, is it possible?

Comment: so if i send the file withing the files section and then retrive, it does work.